# AMChart crashes when I zoom out the chart and hide one of the legend

Tags: charts, amcharts

I have made AmCharts.AmXYChart() for my project.
I am seeeing a strange behaviour.
If I Zoom out the chart and hide one of the legend, the am charts crash and it does not show any thing in the User Interface or it shows it in a small area on browser.
Looks like some java script problem inside the am charts source code.
It should be pretty simple to replicate.
I am providing a small javascript to create the required chart.

```
AmCharts.ready(function() 
{
var chartData = [{x:10, y:14, value:59},
      {x:5, y:3, value:50},
      {x:-10, y:-3, value:19},
      {x:-6, y:5, value:65},
      {x:15, y:-4, value:92},
      {x:13, y:1, value:8},
      {x:1, y:6, value:35}];

var chart = new AmCharts.AmXYChart();        
chart.pathToImages = "../../amcharts/javascript/images/";
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.marginLeft = 35;
chart.startDuration = 1.5;

var xAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
xAxis.position = "left";
xAxis.autoGridCount = true;
chart.addValueAxis(xAxis);

var yAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
yAxis.position = "bottom";
yAxis.autoGridCount = true;
chart.addValueAxis(yAxis);                

var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.valueField = "value";
graph.xField = "x";
graph.yField = "y";
graph.lineAlpha = 0;
graph.bullet = "round";
chart.addGraph(graph);

var chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();
chart.addChartCursor(chartCursor);

var chartScrollbar = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbar();
chartScrollbar.hideResizeGrips = false;
chart.addChartScrollbar(chartScrollbar);

var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
chart.addLegend(legend);

chart.write("chartdiv");
});
```

Please reply if any one knows this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a bug on our side. We will fix it in next update. Meanwhile you can solve it by setting chart.autoMargins = false; and setting margins manually.

Comment: It works, but it does not look like a very easy solution, as there are so many things which can change the look of a graph like (Hiding/Showing Legend, Zoom In/Out) and then one has to figure out the right margin for all these things.

Comment: This problem was fixed in v 3.9.1 and now should work fine without workaround.